# While loops using Await Async.

Tags: loops, asynchronous, while-loop, async-await, ecmascript-next

This Javascript function seems to use the while loop in an asynchronous way. 
Is it the correct way to use while loops with asynchronous conditions?

```
 var Boo;
 var Foo = await getBar(i)
 while(Foo) {
    Boo = await getBar3(i)
    if (Boo) {
      // something
    }
    Foo = await getBar(i)
    i++
  }
```

What I think it does is this:

```
var Boo;
var Foo;
getBar(i).then( (a) => {
  Foo = a;
  if(Foo) {
    getBar3(i).then( (a) => {
      Boo = a
      if(Boo) {
        //something
        i++;
        getBar(i).then( (a} => { Repeat itself...} 
      }
   }
  }
})
```

If that's totally false could you show another way to do it with async await + while loop?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just FYI, async/await is not a part of ES 6.

Comment: await transforms into state machines. You can either have a number of small state machines as you've written (very hard to reason about), or you can have one larger state machine (which is what e.g. C# does).

Comment: What do you mean by "the correct way"? If this code does what you want, then it's correct.

Comment: I could not test it as much as I want and it works as expected in my interpretation of what it should do but not sure if it is not just luck.

Answer (score 44):

> Is it the correct way to use while loops with asynchronous conditions?

Yes. `async function`s simply suspend their execution on every `await` until the respective promises fulfills, and any control structures continue to work as before.

Answer (score 39):

Yep, it's fine to do it like this:

```js
let stopped = false
        
// infinite loop
while(!stopped) {
    let res = await fetch('api link') 
    if (res.something) stopped = true // stop when you want
}
```

But be careful not to get infinite loop

Comment: Be sure to handle the case where `something` is always false, otherwise your loop will stay infinite.

Comment: await can only be used in an async function

Comment: @DavidWelborn top level await is also supported if you configure ts as module

Answer (score 13):

> Is it the correct way to use while loops with asynchronous conditions?

**Yes**, **provided that `getBar` and `getBar3` are asynchronous functions** (marked as async or just returning a `Promise`).

Of course **the execution should be inside an asynchronous context** (inside `async` function)

A possible **issue** that I can see is that initially there are 2 executions of `getBar` with the same `i` and the rest of executions use a mismatched `i` between `while` and `if`. **If this is not the desired behavior** perhaps a more correct version would be:

```js
    (async ()=>{
     while(await getBar(i)) {    
        if (await getBar3(i)) {
          //do something
        }
        i++;
      }
    })();
```

See a mocked example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mwv2cxuy/7/)

Answer (score 3):

### A simple way would be:

```js
// returns a delayed promise 
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

// performs a specific (mathematical) operation every "ms" (milliseconds)
const dec = async (i, ms) => (await delay(ms), --i)

const foo = async () => {
  let i = 5;
  
  // runs an async operation which decreases "i" by 1 every 500ms
  while(i = await dec(i, 500)) 
    // prints 4, 3, 2, 1 with a delay 
    console.log(i) 
}

foo()
```

Here's my [GIST](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/9204a5f22d6a3c5abe58d4cff76ca4d7) if you need to star it to save for later.

#### Alternatively, you can count up:

```js
// returns a delayed promise 
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

// performs a specific (mathematical) operation every "ms" (miliseconds)
const inc = async (i, ms) => (await delay(ms), ++i)

const foo = async () => {
  let i = 0;
  
  // runs an async operation which increases "i" by 1 every 500ms
  while((i = await inc(i, 500)) < 5) {
    // prints 1,2,3,4 with a delay 
    console.log(i) 
  }
}

foo()
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on this example, we see that using `await` in the `while` loop triggers **SYNCHRONOUS** code execution. In other words, until one iteration of the loop is completed, the SECOND one WILL NOT BE STARTED

```js
let counter = 0;

const promise = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 2000)
  );

(async() => {
  console.log("Start")
  console.time('allTime');
  while (counter < 3) {
    await promise();
    console.log('Resolve promise', counter);
    counter++;
  }
  console.timeEnd('allTime');
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `while` loop body works synchronously, we need to move our code out of the body.
This solution might help someone:

```
while(await (async () => {
  Boo = await getBar3(i)
  if (Boo) {
    // something
  }
  Foo = await getBar(i)
  i++
  return Foo; // you must return the condition that the loop depends on it
})()); // Adding this semicolon is crucial
```

Answer (score -1):

Its been awhile since this question was asked.  I am new to js after many years of other languages (starting with punch cards and paper tape) and needed to solve this problem.  Here is my answer:

```
var loopContinue = true;
var n = 0;

async function  Managework() {
  while (loopContinue) {  //seemingly an infinite loop
    //await (doWork(n));
    await (doWork(n).catch(() => { loopContinue=false; }));
    n++;
    console.log(`loop counter ${n}`);
  }
  console.log(`loop exit n=${n} loopContinue=${loopContinue}`);
 }

Managework();

function doWork(n) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`dowork(${n})`);
    if (n > 5) {
      //loopContinue = false;
      reject(`done`);
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('ok');
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

As desired the loop breaks after the 5th iteration.  'loopContinue' global can either be set in the work function or in the catch (or could be the then) of the promise.  I tired just using 'break' in the then or catch but I get an error.

If you want to do it in doWork you can eliminate the catch and and just call doWork()  and uncomment the // loopContinue= false in doWork.  Either way works.  This was tested with node.js

I found stuff on nextTick but this seems much easier.