# Does GC wait for recursive chains to resolve before cleaning up function-scoped vars?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Looking at Task Manager I see memory usage of my node.js process increasing continuously - so a memory leak. I'm implementing a loop via recursion, could this be the cause?

The code below does the following:

1. extracts about 64KB from a flatfile via a generator function into the `batch` variable
2. batches consist of lines - each line is retrieved from the 64kb batch iteratively
3. each line has x number of transformations applied to it
4. Each batch is sent over the network

Is it possible that the `batch` variable is waiting until the recursive chain resolves before being cleaned up by the GC?

```
await (async function nextBatch() {
    const batch = batches.next();
    const payload = [];
    if (batch.done) return;
    const values = batch.value;

    await asyncForEach(values, async(item) => {
        await asyncForEach(transformations, async(t) => {
            item = await t.transform.call(t, item);
        });
        if (item !== {} && item) payload.push(item);
    });

    const loadResult = await load.batch(payload);

    await nextBatch();
})();
```

I get the following error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[21760:0000020D47008EF0]   935709 ms: Mark-sweep 1406.7 (1472.4) -> 1406.5 (1444.4) MB, 380.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 381 ms) last resort GC in old space requested
[21760:0000020D47008EF0]   936051 ms: Mark-sweep 1406.5 (1444.4) -> 1406.5 (1444.4) MB, 341.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000002D779C25EE1 <JSObject>
    2: new constructor(aka Parser) [C:\MSc\Thesis\netl\node_modules\csv-parse\lib\index.js:167] [bytecode=000002935CBD0F09 offset=452](this=0000014FD4695319 <Parser map = 000001D4E8BB1749>,/* anonymous */=0000034EC0F9C829 <Object map = 000001D4E8BAB341>)
    5: /* anonymous */ [C:\MSc\Thesis\netl\node_modules\csv-parse\lib\sync.js:20] [bytecode=000002935CBD0599 offset=114](this=0000011FD4F8BF9...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::SetClassFunctionInstanceDescriptor
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFunction
 6: v8::internal::Factory::NewFunctionFromSharedFunctionInfo
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewFunctionFromSharedFunctionInfo
 8: v8::internal::compiler::Pipeline::AllocateRegistersForTesting
 9: 00000362273847A1
```

Comment: "I'm implementing a loop via recursion", you're what? As far as I know something is either a loop (code repeated with some counter or condition, not stacked), or recursion (function or method calling itself, and pushed onto stack), not both.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You can implement recursion with a loop and a stack, and you can implement loops with recursion. https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2

Comment: the logic is run multiple times, triggered by a call to the `nextBatch` function which is done recursively if the loop invariant remains true - i.e. if the generator (batches.next) is 'not done'

Comment: looking at the link @melpomene - it would seem that it's likely that the variables `batch` and `payload` are remaining in memory until the recursion is complete... I think I could set them to null manually, but is there a better way?

Comment: or declare them in parent scope...

Comment: Can't this code be converted to a straight loop?

Comment: @melpomene - yes, it looks like i can replace the recursive call with a while loop. before I was using callbacks and not async await. so i didn't see that. thank you

Comment: ah: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110762/while-loops-using-await-async