# Why does my code stop working after few loops?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I am running my code, it stops working after a few iterations.

```js
function wait(delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("");
    }, delay);
  });
}
let t = 0;
async function n() {
  while (t < 10) {
    let i = t + 3;
 console.log("i < 5 ?",i,i<5)
    while (i < 5) {
      console.log("starting i...");
      await wait(800);
      console.log(i);
      i++;
    }
    let u = t + 4;
 console.log("u< 5 ?",u,u<5)
    while (u < 5) {
      console.log("starting u +...");
      await wait(800);
      console.log(u);
      u++;
    }
    t++;
  }
}
n();
```

**Output:**

```
     starting i...
     3
     starting i...
     4
     starting i +...
     4
     starting i...
```

Does somebody see an error in my code?

Comment: I made a snippet and added a console.log that will tell you why you do not see the rest

Comment: Why do you print `starting i + ...` in the second loop, shouldn't that say `starting u + ...`?

Comment: What are you expecting to be logged instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `while` loop doesn't await anything and will be executed directly.

then, you wrote

```js
let i = t + 3; // First iteration == 4, second == 5
console.log("i < 5 ?",i,i<5)
while (i < 5) {
 // ...
}
```

But `i` will be, at the second loop, equal to `5` -> it wont run anymore, and the same for the `u`.

So it will only run one, same as to say that your first `while` is kind of useless.

You could provide more information if the answer didn't helped you, and I'll enhance it.

#### Response to the comment bellow

*can I make my first loop wait for completing the inner 2 while loops?*

```js
function wait(delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('')
    }, delay)
  })
}
let t = 0
async function n() {
  while (t < 10) {
    let i = t + 3
    console.log('i < 5 ?', i, i < 5)
    ;async () => {
      while (i < 5) {
        console.log('starting i...')
        await wait(800)
        console.log(i)
        i++
      }
    }
    let u = t + 4
    console.log('u< 5 ?', u, u < 5)
    ;async () => {
      while (u < 5) {
        console.log('starting u +...')
        await wait(800)
        console.log(u)
        u++
      }
    }
    t++
  }
}
n()
```

Comment: OK I understand, but now can I make my first loop wait for completing the inner 2 while loops, I mean outer while loop will wait for each iteration until 2 inner while loops are not finished

Comment: It's an other question that already have [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60526968/11135174), please do accept the answer or extend your question if it does not satisfy your expectation.

Comment: I did provide an example though, but still, the logic with the `t` variable does not make any sense. What are you trying to archive ?