# await and async don't work in the recursive function

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, node-mysql

I'm trying to connect the code to MySQL. When the connection fails in first attempt, I want it to reattempt to connect.
So, This code is used recursive function.

This code contains DB connect process.

```ts
const mysql = require('mysql');
let connection;
let cnt = 0;


export const cm_dbconnect =  async() => {

    let result = false;

  
    var dbInfo = {
      host     : '127.0.0.1',
      user     : '****',
      password : '**********'
    }

    let db =  mysql.createConnection(dbInfo);
    
    const attemptConnection = async() => {
    console.log('Attempting to connect to db')
   
    
    
    db.connect(async function (err) {
      if (err) {
        
        cnt += 1;
        console.log('Error connecting to database, try again in 1 sec...')
        db.destroy() 
        if (cnt<5) {
        console.log(cnt);
        
        function settimeoutpromise() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                cm_dbconnect();
                resolve("end")
            }, 1000);
        })}
        await settimeoutpromise();
    
        } 
      } 
    })
    
    
  }
  await attemptConnection()

            
  
  module.exports  = db;
  result = true
  return  {result: result, errCode: "", errDetail: ""};


}
```

And this code contains controller.

```ts
export const Controller = async () => {
   

    let connect = await cm_dbconnect();
          
    let db = require('');
    let sql = 'select *** from ***;';
    db.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
      
    })
    
    console.log("aaaa");
    console.log(connect);


       }
let test = Controller();
```

However, the result is returned before the retry is finished. I think this is why await/async doesn't work.

```
Attempting to connect to db
aaaa
{ result: true, errCode: '', errDetail: '' }
Error connecting to database, try again in 1 sec...
1
undefined
Attempting to connect to db
Error connecting to database, try again in 1 sec...
2
Attempting to connect to db
Error connecting to database, try again in 1 sec...
3
Attempting to connect to db
Error connecting to database, try again in 1 sec...
4
Attempting to connect to db
Error connecting to database, try again in 1 sec...
```

I want to get return value after retrying if the 5 times connection fails.
please tell me solution for this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It seems you are not returning promise instance, but taking its values using `then` in `connect`.

Comment: Sorry. I repaired program drastically. I want to get return value after retrying if  the 5 times connection fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way your are creating the connection :

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const cm_dbconnect =  async() => {
  
    var dbInfo = {
      host     : '127.0.0.1',
      user     : '****',
      password : '**********'
    }

    let db =  mysql.createConnection(dbInfo);
  
    try
    {
              await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.connect(err => {
                return err ? reject(err) : resolve({status: 'OK', message: 'Connected to DB'})
              })
           })
           
          
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        ...handle errors...
    }

  module.exports  = cm_dbconnect;
```

In your controller:

```
const cm_dbconnect = require('path')
export const Controller = async () => {
   
    let connect = await cm_dbconnect();
    let count;
// already called once 
    while( connect.err && count < 4) {
        count++;
        connect = await cm_dbconnect();
    }
    
   if( connect.err && count >=4) return 'DB not connected at the moment'
  
    console.log(`Connected with DB after this many tries`);
          
    let db = require('');
    let sql = 'select *** from ***;';
    db.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
      
    })
    
    console.log("aaaa");
    console.log(connect);


       }
let test = Controller();
```

I have changed the DB connection to get promise based on connection, in the controller we are checking what is being returned.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110762/while-loops-using-await-async) thread, it has good way to solve the problem too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I write roop(retry) process in cm_dbconnect function? If possible, I want to keep the controller simple .

Comment: Yes, you can write it and make a different function which helps to retry with db connection. If the answer helps, you can accept that and upvoye it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Let me ask you a few questions.

Comment: 1. connect.err don't work because ”Cannot read property 'err' of undefined”.
2. I want the retry interval to be 1 second. So, settimeout function can be used,  where should I insert this function?

Comment: Connect.err is just a pseudocode to make sure loop only runs when we have error.

Comment: If you need to insert the settimeout we can't use the while loop anymore. need to come up with better solution. I will update that shortly.